# Optimization - Optimal velocity for fuel consumption

Tags: derivatives, optimization, graphing-functions, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

*I am working through a series of questions for my 1st year uni maths course and I am really stuck here so any help would be appreciated. I know how to optimize 3D objects and areas but just can't work out how to get the starting formula(e) here in which I will use to find the minimum stationary point of the graph. Thanks.*

The cost per hour of running a train is proportional to:

$$100 + \frac {v^2}{36}$$

where $v$ (in mph) is the average speed of the journey.

Find the speed $v$ that makes the trip cheapest when the distance is $400$ miles.

Comment: In short: You know the cost per hour, so the total cost is that times the duration of the trip. You are not given the trip duration, but can you figure it out given the other things you know (the distance and the average speed)?

Comment: Just noticed that this is actually a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370339/optimization-most-economical-speed-to-travel-for-400mile-journey).

Comment: Any particular reason that you reposted your earlier question with no useful changes?

Answer (score -1):

Average speed (t = total time): $$v= \frac{400}{t}\tag{1}$$

Cost per hour: $$C_h = k(100+\frac{v^2}{36})\tag{2}$$

Total cost: $$C=C_h\cdot t \tag{3}$$
Insert $(1)$ in $(2)$, then $(2)$ in $(3)$ and differentiate $(3)$.